# Как сделать перенос строки в новом файле PHP

Tags: php, fopen

```
<?php
    
    $newfile = fopen('a.txt', 'a+b');
    fwrite($newfile, 'Это новый текстовый файл \n Он создан с помощью PHP');
    fclose($newfile);

?>
```

Comment: В двойных кавычках: `"Текст\nТекст"`

Comment: Вместо \n лучше использовать константу [PHP_EOL](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.constants.php) для кросс-платформенной совместимости.